# Difference between calling a service method in drupal 8

Tags: php, drupal, dependency-injection, drupal-8

I want to know what difference does it make when i call a service this way :

```
$service = \Drupal::service('myservice.method');
$service->methodNameInService();
```

or this way (Dependency Injecton)

```
 public function __construct(MyService $myService) {
+    $this->myService = $myService;
   }

public function test() {
    // Call function from service 
    $this->myService->methodNameInService();

}
```

Is this better for performance or is it just only the right way and has it zero effect on performance or something else?